# I don't understand some arguments for the xrandr command

Tags: x11, xrandr, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

Considering these arguments:

> `--listproviders`
>
>   Report information about the providers available.
>
> `--setprovideroutputsource provider source`
>
>   Set source as the source of display output images for provider.  This is only possible if source and provider have the Source Output and Sink Output capabilities, respectively.  If source is 0x0, then provider is disconnected from its current output source.
>
> `--setprovideroffloadsink provider sink`
>
>   Set provider as a render offload device for sink.  This is only possible if provider and sink have the Source Offload and Sink Offload capabilities, respectively.  If sink is 0x0, then provider is disconnected from its current render offload sink.

What does the documentation mean by "sink", "provider", "source" and "offload"?

My end goal is to be able to use my AMD graphics driver for graphics intensive applications.

I have an integrated Intel graphics card and a discrete AMD graphics card.

Comment: These arguments are for a situation where one graphics card can display images rendered by another graphics card, see e.g. [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html). Another option is to simply use the more powerful graphics card directly (if the system supports that).